# How does CiviCRM handle https requests to a mutually authenticated SSL server?

Tags: dashboard, dashlet

I first ran into this because I was experiencing the issue described at this post: forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=6090.0

I'm getting an error when I use the simple curl request script " Connected to example.org (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0) * Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb * skipping SSL peer certificate verification * NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified) * NSS error -12227 (SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT)

So, does CiviCRM rely on NSS for a client PKI cert (our server verifies client  certificates before allowing access)?

Thanks!

Comment: So what's the context, when is this happening and what do the users do to trigger that?

Comment: If you reference the post, in the description, much of the context  is there, but essentially, users logging in to a CiviCRM install on top of a mutually authenticated server are greeted with a broken dashboard (dashlets do not load)